# Change to hour and min format in superset

Tags: sql, apache-superset

I have a column `durationInSeconds`.
I used that column and pulled in as metric and used custom sql as `SUM(durationInSeconds)`
I am getting the result in the format 49.2B.

How can I change this to hour and min format? I am using superset.

Answer (score 0):

Use this metric to convert into minutes.

```
SELECT ROUND(durationInSeconds/60, 0)
```

Comment: SELECT ROUND(durationInSeconds/60, 0) this is only in min but I do want it to be in hour and min eg: 5842h 26m